# Hibernate merge leads to duplicate entries in @ElementCollection

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I have an Entity:

```java
@Entity
public class TestEntity {
    
    private List<String> collection;
    private String id;
    
    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin")
    public String getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setID(String value) {
        this.id = value;
    }
    
    @ElementCollection
    public List<String> getCollection() {
        return this.collection;
    }

    public void setCollection(List<String> collection) {
        this.collection = collection;
    }

}
```

And a short piece of code:

```java
String newId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
TestEntity entity = new TestEntity();
entity.setCollection(new ArrayList<>());
entity.setID(newId);

EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
transaction.begin();
em.persist(entity);
transaction.commit();
em.close();
            
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    entity.getCollection().add(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    transaction = em.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();
    TestEntity merged = em.merge(entity);
    transaction.commit();
    em.close();
}
```

**My problem is the following:**
For each iteration in the loop, when the `entity` gets an additional `collection`-entry, is merged, and committed, I expect hibernate to emit these SQL-statements (here for the second iteration):

```sql
delete from TestEntity_conllection where TestEntity_ID='ff9c495b-2707-4004-8123-e470cc71e779'
insert into TestEntity_conllection (TestEntity_ID, connectionIDs) values ('ff9c495b-2707-4004-8123-e470cc71e779', '84628fb3-c516-497f-877e-9bbb02e79be1')
insert into TestEntity_conllection (TestEntity_ID, connectionIDs) values ('ff9c495b-2707-4004-8123-e470cc71e779', '439b0edb-afd1-4cec-bc0e-9730da4f51ae')
```

However, the first `delete`-statement is simply missing. Therefore Hibernate is happily adding duplicate entries from the former iterations. Afterwards my `testentity_collection`-table looks like this containing many duplicate entries:

| TestEntity_ID | collection |
| --- | --- |
| ff9c495b-2707-4004-8123-e470cc71e779 | 84628fb3-c516-497f-877e-9bbb02e79be1 |
| ff9c495b-2707-4004-8123-e470cc71e779 | 84628fb3-c516-497f-877e-9bbb02e79be1 |
| ff9c495b-2707-4004-8123-e470cc71e779 | 439b0edb-afd1-4cec-bc0e-9730da4f51ae |
| ff9c495b-2707-4004-8123-e470cc71e779 | 84628fb3-c516-497f-877e-9bbb02e79be1 |
| ff9c495b-2707-4004-8123-e470cc71e779 | 439b0edb-afd1-4cec-bc0e-9730da4f51ae |
| ff9c495b-2707-4004-8123-e470cc71e779 | c6bb7ef1-f679-4b1c-bdfc-06ed1e12e60e |
| ff9c495b-2707-4004-8123-e470cc71e779 | 84628fb3-c516-497f-877e-9bbb02e79be1 |
| ff9c495b-2707-4004-8123-e470cc71e779 | 439b0edb-afd1-4cec-bc0e-9730da4f51ae |
| ff9c495b-2707-4004-8123-e470cc71e779 | c6bb7ef1-f679-4b1c-bdfc-06ed1e12e60e |
| ff9c495b-2707-4004-8123-e470cc71e779 | 15edb341-c6c3-433e-8d1f-c624844e5d08 |

**The problem does not arise, if** I create `entity` without an empty `List` in the `collection`-field by moving the line `entity.setCollection(new ArrayList<>());` down below the first transaction. Also it's gone, if I put a `List` with at least one entry instead of an empty `List` into the `collection`, initially.

Do I somehow use Hibernates `merge`-function wrong, or is it really a bug in Hibernate?

Comment: The difference is that after `persist()`, the collection initialized by hibernate is a `PersistentBag` and the merge mechanism seems to be different from the one with an ArrayList. When it's an ArrayList, the collection is rebuilt from scratch. When its a persistentBag, during merge,  the collection is not rebuilt and hibernate does not take care of the element already present in the collection. Hibernate seems to be confused by this persistentBag coming from a previously closed entitymanager. The differential mechanism does not work as excepted in this case.

Comment: Of course, you could workaround this weird behaviour by reloading `entity` inside the loop before adding the String in the collection. (in this case there no need to merge)

Comment: @PierreDemeestere I have just checked in the debugger: After `persist()`, the collection is always converted from `ArrayList` to `PersistentBag`, whether it was an empty or filled `ArrayList`. However, the behaviour differs in both cases.

Regarding your suggestion for a workaround: Unfortunately, the production code is different. It is a generic function that can take a variety of entities and should update them by using `merge()`. Without `merge()` a workaround would have to contain specific code to update each of the different entity-classes.

Comment: You right, after persist the collection is always a PersistenBag, that's why you have to replace it with a new ArrayList() afterwards to make it work.

Comment: So, before calling merge, can you replace the PersistentBag by an ArrayList (also moving contained elements from the PersistentBag to the ArrayList if the collection is not empty).

Comment: No, I don't have to replace it with a `new ArrayList()` after initial creation. If I initialised it with either `null` or a non-empty `ArrayList`, it just works. It is replaced by Hibernate with a `PersistentBag`. I can get this `PersistenBag` and `add(...)` to it a new item and it just works... Except for when I initialised it with an empty `new ArrayList()` in the first place.